# Moving mouse pointer on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, mouse, accessibilityservice, eye-tracking

I am developing an eye-tracking application that moves a mouse pointer based on the coordinates of the eyes.
I successfully detected the coordinates of the eyes but wasn't able to create a mouse pointer that moves accordingly.
I am a beginner in Android development and I am really stuck at this point.
to clarify my question I need the pointer to move like on [eva facial mouse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.crea_si.eviacam.service&hl=en) except using the eyes coordinates instead of the faces.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe we have any APIs to move the mouse. The Eva site mentions that it moves a pointer "like a mouse".

I suspect what they are doing is drawing a pointer on an accessibility overlay, and then using AccessibilityService#dispatchGesture to simulate the user touching the screen.